# Priority Queue implementation for top k frequent elements leetcode in Ruby

Tags: algorithm, ruby, heap

While working on the following leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/ I used a Priority Queu implementation in Ruby. I have learned how to implement a Priority Queu in Java in  [Robert Sedgewick's Algorithms book](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/). When inserting Hashes into the Priority Queue for example `{ 1 => 3}` this made me refactored the Priotity's Queue in such a way so I was able to compare two hashes values.

The implementation is much straight forward when your dealing with numbers and characters but it made me wonder what would be the best implementation with using objects or hashes.

```
def top_k_frequent(nums, k)
  ans = []
  h = Hash.new(0)

  nums.each do |num|
    h[num] += 1
  end

  heap = Heap.new
  h.each do |k,v|
    heap.insert({k => v})
  end

  k.times do
    a = heap.del_max
    ans.push(a.keys[0])
  end

  ans
end


class Heap
  def initialize
    @n = 0
    @pq = []
  end

  def insert(v)
    @pq[@n += 1] = v
    swim(@n)
  end

  def swim(k)
    while k > 1 && less((k / 2).floor, k)
      swap((k / 2).floor, k)
      k = k/2
    end
  end

  def swap(i, j)
    temp = @pq[i]
    @pq[i] = @pq[j]
    @pq[j] = temp
  end

  def less(i, j)
    @pq[i].values[0] < @pq[j].values[0]
  end

  def del_max
    max = @pq[1]
    swap(1, @n)
    @n -= 1
    @pq[@n + 1] = nil
    sink(1)
    max
  end

  def sink(k)
    while 2 * k <= @n
      j = 2 * k

      if !@pq[j + 1].nil?
        j += 1 if j > 1 && @pq[j].values[0] < @pq[j + 1].values[0]
      end
      break if !less(k, j)

      swap(k, j)
      k = j
    end
  end
end
```

There are a few things that come to mind that I wish to probably learn. Keep in mind that I would like to prepare for algorithm interviews and so I would like to avoid as much synthetic sugar as possible.

- `@pq[j].values[0]` check for example how to get to a hash values I need to use `values[0]` is there a better way for this?
- There are 3 loops in the `top_k_frequent` method. How would yo go about optimizing this implementation?
- `a.keys[0]` notice how I get the key of the element in Ruby is there a cleaner way of doing this?

This brought to my attention that in case of dealing with more complex objects the Priority Queue's API might be needed to refactored to be able to compare between objects, what would be the best way of dealing with that? Would creating another class which you pass to the Priority Queue would be a better solution?

Here is the implementation I have for Priority Queue's prior to editing to deal with hashes.

```
class Heap
  attr_accessor :pq, :n

  def initialize
    @pq = [] # heap order complete binary tree
    @n = 0 # in pq[1..N] with pq[0] unused
  end

  def empty?
    @n == 0
  end

  def size
    @n
  end

  def insert(v)
    @pq[@n += 1] = v
    swim(@n) # position in heap
  end

  # trickleup
  def swim(k)
    while k > 1 && less((k / 2).floor, k) # parent: k/2 parent less than child?
      swap((k/2).floor, k)
      k = k / 2
    end
  end

  def del_max
    max = @pq[1]  # Retrieve max key from top.
    swap(1, @n) # Exchange with last item.
    @n -= 1
    @pq[@n + 1] = nil # Avoid loitering. max added to end on swap make nil
    sink(1) # Restore HEAP property
    max
  end

  # Trickledown
  def sink(k)
    while 2 * k <= @n
      j = 2 * k # child

      if !@pq[j + 1].nil? # check if there is a right child
        j += 1 if j > 1 && @pq[j] < @pq[j + 1] # if left child less than right child
      end
      break if @pq[k] > @pq[j] # If parent greater than child break

      swap(k, j)
      k = j
    end
  end

  def less(i, j)
    @pq[i] < @pq[j]
  end

  def swap(i, j)
    temp = @pq[i]
    @pq[i] = @pq[j]
    @pq[j] = temp
  end
end
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by "deal with hashes". Why would that be a problem? A priority queue stores values according to an associated priority, it doesn't really care what the values it stores are.

Comment: @JörgWMittag well I agree with you that values are stored according to an associated priority but I disagree with you on "It doesn't really care what the values it stores are". In order for there to be a comparison values must be compared. It is not the same comparing `"A" < "B"`, or `1 < 2`  with comparing objects. `obj_1` < `obj_2`, in this case the API must be implemented in such a way that is able to compare `obj_1` with `obj_2` just in the case shown above. Notice how I need to use `@pq[j].values[0]` in order to get to the value. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html

Comment: Ah, so, in your priority queue, the element and the priority are the same thing? In other words, you are using the natural ordering of the elements? In that case, it is still trivial to deal with hashes: hashes don't have a natural ordering, so they cannot be stored in a priority queue whose ordering is the natural ordering of the elements.

Comment: @JörgWMittag you can that is how I solved this leetcode question  https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/

Comment: It is still not clear to me how you decide the priority of a hash. For example, what is the priority of `{ [] => {}, 'two' => 2.0, 3 => :three, Time.now => Object.new }`? Normally, a priority queue stores items with associated priority. In your implementation, you store items *without* an associated priority, instead the item itself is the priority. However, that obviously limits you to only storing items that have a natural total ordering, e.g. numbers or strings. But objects in general, including hashes, are neither totally ordered nor do they have a natural ordering.

Comment: I guess this is about priority queues, but there are simpler ways to solve the problem: [1,1,1,2,2,3].tally.max_by(2,&:last).map(&:first) #=> [1,2]`.

Answer (score 1):

The objects in the priority queue (as implemented above) have their priority determined by `<`, `>`, and `==`. So however equality is defined for the object determines its priority. For numbers and strings, this is fairly obvious but the default implementation of equality, less than and greater than for hashes may surprise you and not give the result you are expecting.

Perhaps you could consider passing in a block to your initialize method to allow you to provide your own comparison function in those cases where the default one doesn't match your needs. Like `Enumerable::sort` does.

Comment: Hashes simply *do not have* a default implementation of `Comparable` at all, precisely because there is no sensible natural ordering.

Comment: Hash A is considered to be 'less than' hash B if A is a subset of B, and this appears to be true even if `a == {}`. See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-3C

Comment: A priority queue requires a total ordering, though, which this isn't. (Hence why hashes don't implement `Comparable`.) Sorry, I should have written "a natural ordering that is also total". Strings have at least two different natural orderings that are also total (lexicographic and length), numbers have an obvious natural total ordering. (Well, integers, reals, rationals, at least; complex numbers is a different matter.) For hashes, I don't see that. The OP is using the ordering of the value of the first key-value-pair which to me seems to be totally random.

Comment: *`priority determined by`* `<`, `>` in `sink(k)`, but `less(i, j)` in `swim(k)`.